# juego el ahorcado en python

Tags: python

estoy creando el juego del ahorcado en python, sin embargo estoy estancada en la parte de verificar si la palabra contiene esa letra mas de 2 veces, entonces que vaya tachandolas segun la persona las coloque, sin embargo  no sabria como plantearlo, alguna idea?

```
import random

listaPalabras=['amor', 'boda', 'adivinanza', 'amarillo', 'silla','telefono', 'ballena', 'radio', 'automovil']

def seleccionRandom(listaPalabras):
    return random.choice(listaPalabras) #escojo palabra random de la lista


seleccionRandom(listaPalabras)

palabraEscogida = [] #creo lista
palabraEscogida.append(seleccionRandom(listaPalabras)) #guardo la palabra random en la lista
print(palabraEscogida) #imprimo la palabra random en la lista

print("comienza el juego! Se eligio una palabra al azar y tendras que adivinar la misma, introduce las letras que creas que tenga, tienes 5 intentos para adivinar la letra, si fallas quedas descalificado ")
letra=input("introduce una letra para saber si esta dentro de la palabra: ")



def verificacionLetra(letra):
  contador = 0

  while letra in palabraEscogida[0]:
    contador=contador+1
    print(f' la letra, {letra}, esta y has ganado, {contador}, punto')
    letra=input("introduce otra letra para saber si esta dentro de la palabra: ")
    print(palabraEscogida)


  else:
    contador=contador-1
    print(f'la letra, {letra}, no esta y tienes puntos, {contador}')
    letra=input("introduce otra letra para saber si esta dentro de la palabra: ")
    print(palabraEscogida)

verificacionLetra(letra)
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: pero.. si encontras una letra, y no la seguis buscando (en tu while letra in palabra) como esperas encontrar mas de una letra igual? lo que esta mal planteada es tu logica... es repetitica, confusa.. por ejemplo, que pasa si fallo la primer letra que elijo? el programa termina ahi?

Comment: estoy intentando antes de ver si esta la letra en la palabra, verificar si esta mas de 2 veces entonces hacer algo, en este caso en la realidad seria tachar la primera letra y seguir preguntando otra letra, si coincide tachar la otra hasta que quede en 0 pero en codigo no sabria como ilustrarlo @JheymanMejia

Comment: esto es un borrador, aun esta en edicion @gbianchi porque no sabria que hacer si hay mas de 2 letras iguales

Comment: Pensalo en funciones... pensa en papel antes que en codigo.. tus funciones, hacen demasiadas cosas que no deberian hacer.. usa el principio de responsabilidad.. cada cosa, se encarga de una sola cosa... Una funcion pide las letras.. otra comprueba si estan en la palabra.. y asi seguis, hasta que muere o adivina la palabra.. pero no mezcles las cosas..

Answer (score 2):

Revolver tu pregunta posiblemente requiera reescribir tu código casi al completo para cambiar el "enfoque" pero te puedo dar unas pistas en forma de métodos que te pueden ayudar a replantear el problema.

Puedes usar el método `count()` en una lista y te devuelve cuantas coincidencias existen.

```
palabra = "amor"
palabra.count("a")
# Devuelve 1 porque solo hay una "a"
```

No necesitas crear una lista de palabras escogidas porque solo has escogido una palabra, así que puedes simplificar esa parte.

Puedes convertir una cadena de texto en una lista usando `list()`.

```
palabra = "amor"
lista = list(palabra)
>>>> ['a', 'm', 'o', 'r']
```

Normalmente en el juego del ahorcado sabes al menos cuantas letras tiene la palabra, eso lo puedes hacer con el método `len()`.

```
palabra = "amor"
len(palabra)
>>>> 4
```

Puedes recorrer una lista de principio a fin (por ejemplo) con un for loop y comprobar qué letra está en qué posición y rellenarlo si coincide con alguna en la palabra o poner una "X", un "#" o un "_" en el lugar que no coincida para indicar los huecos.

```
intento = input()
lista = list("amor")
for letra in lista:
    if intento in letra:
    # etc, etc...
```

También deberías tener claro cuantos intentos puedes tener porque normalmente son fijos y cuando los acabas termina el juego. Eso puedes hacerlo o bien con un `while()` y reducir en 1 o un `for` tantas veces como intentos.

Hay tantas maneras de resolverlo como personas hay en el mundo (cada uno tiene la suya) pero estos conceptos deberían ayudarte

Sigue intentándolo y si tienes más dudas con el código pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Este problema se puede resolver más fácil usando una lista de letras y otra lista con un caracter que quieras para ocultar las letras. A la segunda lista se le va reemplazando los caracteres por las letras a según el usuario las vaya develando.

Mirando ese concepto en la consola:

```
>>> palabra = "silla"
>>> listaLetras = list(palabra)
>>> long_palabra = len(listaLetras)
>>> listaLetras
['s', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'a']
>>> lista_ = ['_' for _ in range(long_palabra)]
>>> lista_ # lista de guiones
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
>>> letra = "l" # entrada del usuario
>>> for i in range(long_palabra):
...     if listaLetras[i] == letra:
...         lista_[i] = letra
...
>>> lista_
['_', '_', 'l', 'l', '_']
```

Ahora es cuestión de agregarle controles: cuando la cantidad de intentos se agote, o cuando el usuario ha ganado.

Un ejemplo funcional puede ser este.

```
import random

def imprimir(listaActual):
    print(' '.join(listaActual))

max_intentos = 5
listaPalabras = ['amor', 'boda', 'adivinanza', 'amarillo', 'silla', 
'telefono', 'ballena', 'radio', 'automovil']

palabraEscogida = random.choice(listaPalabras)
listaLetras = list(palabraEscogida)
longLista = len(listaLetras) # longitud de la palabra
lista_ = ['_' for _ in range(longLista)] # Lista de guiones bajos [_, _, _, ...]

imprimir(lista_)
ganador = False
contador = 0
while max_intentos > 0:
    letra = input(f"Intentos [{max_intentos}] - Introduce una letra: ")
    acierto = False
    for i in range(longLista):
        if listaLetras[i] == letra:
            lista_[i] = letra # reemplaza _ por la letra actual
            contador += 1
            acierto = True
    if not acierto: # La letra no está
        max_intentos -= 1
    imprimir(lista_)
    if contador == longLista: # Se adivinaron todas la letras
        ganador = True
        break
        
if ganador:
    print(" *** Ganaste el juego ***")
else:
    print(f"[!] Perdiste el juego, la palabra era: {palabraEscogida}")
```

Produce una salida así:

```
_ _ _ _ _
Intentos [5] - Introduce una letra: l
_ _ _ _ _
Intentos [4] - Introduce una letra: a
_ a _ _ _
Intentos [4] - Introduce una letra: e
_ a _ _ _
Intentos [3] - Introduce una letra: d
_ a d _ _
Intentos [3] - Introduce una letra: r
r a d _ _
Intentos [3] - Introduce una letra: i
r a d i _
Intentos [3] - Introduce una letra: o
r a d i o
 *** Ganaste el juego ***
```

Con eso ya puedes adaptar o personalizar el concepto a tu código, modificar los mensajes o agregar otros, por ejemplo, cuando el usuario falla.

Potenciales problemas de este código: Si un usuario vuelve a escoger una letra que ya salió, lo toma como entrada válida, aunque no influye el resultado final. Si es necesario, podrías usar una tercera lista para comparar si la entrada del usuario, haya fallado o no, ya está ahi.

Answer (score 0):

trate de mejorar el codigo anterior pero aun sigo sin saber como sustituir la primera ocurrencia de una letra repetida por un *

import random

```
listaPalabras=['amor', 'boda', 'adivinanza', 'amarillo', 'silla','telefono', 'ballena', 'radio', 'automovil']



def seleccionRandom(listaPalabras):
    global palabraRandom
    palabraRandom=random.choice(listaPalabras)
    print(palabraRandom)
    #escojo palabra random de la lista
def guardaPalabraRandom(palabraRandom):
    palabraEscogida = []
    palabraEscogida.append(palabraRandom)
    print(palabraEscogida)

seleccionRandom(listaPalabras)
guardaPalabraRandom(palabraRandom)
contador = 0
letra=input('introduzca una letra para adivinar la palabra: ')
if letra in palabraRandom:
    if palabraRandom.count(letra) >1:
       palabraRandom = palabraRandom.replace(letra, '*')
       print(palabraRandom)
       contador=contador+1
       print(contador)
    else:
      palabraRandom=palabraRandom.replace(letra, '*')
      print(palabraRandom)
      contador=contador+1
      print(contador)

else:
    print(f'la letra {letra}, no esta')
    contador=contador-1
    print(contador)
```

sera que pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Añade este código a continuación de tu propia pregunta en lugar de responderte a ti misma si está relacionado todavia con tu problema o abre una nueva pregunta si es diferente. Puedes responderte a ti misma, pero solo si has solucionado el problema propuesto. Un saludo

Comment: Esto que es? una respuesta? u otra pregunta?