# Problema con bucles for anidado en Python

Tags: python

tengo un problema con un ejercicio de python:
El ejercicio consiste en pedir una palabra y el numero de intentos para adivinarla.
Se puede adivinar letra a letra como si fuese el juego del ahorcado o la palabra completa.
Si se elige adivinar por letras, hay que pedir al usuario una letra y si aparece en la palabra que hemos introducido nos mostrara la palabra con las letras que hayamos adivinado y las letras que no adivinemos nos apareceran como un asterisco.

```
@classmethod
    def adivinar_palabra(self):
        print("Adivine letra introduzca 1:")
        print("Adivine palabra introducida 0:")
        opciones = int(input())

        if opciones == 1:
            letra_adivinar = input("Adivine letra:")
            self.lista_letras_intentos.append(letra_adivinar)
            for x in self.palabra:
                self.lista_letras.append(x)
                self.palabra_asteriscos = '*' * len(self.palabra)

            for x in self.palabra_asteriscos:
                self.lista_letras_asterisco.append(x)

            for x in range(0, len(self.lista_letras)):
                if self.lista_letras[x] == letra_adivinar:

                    for x in range(0, len(self.lista_letras_asterisco)):
                        self.lista_letras_asterisco[x] = letra_adivinar
                    print("Intento correcto. Existe la letra. ", self.lista_letras_asterisco, ".", self.intentos_permitidos,
                          "intentos disponibles")
                elif self.lista_letras[x] != letra_adivinar:
                    self.intentos_permitidos -= 1
                    print("Intento erróneo. No existe la letra. ", self.lista_letras_asterisco, ".", self.intentos_permitidos,
                          "intentos disponibles")

        elif opciones == 0:
            Juego_palabra.mostrar_palabra()
        print("Los intentos numero de letras fueron los siguientes: ", self.lista_intento_numeros)
        print("Los intentos de letras fueron los siguientes: ", self.lista_letras_intentos)
        print("Los intentos de palabras fueron los siguientes: ", self.lista_palabras_completas_intentos)
```

La ejecución seria como se muestra en la imagen, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si alguien me puede echar una mano lo agradecería.

Comment: Dices que tienes un problema con bucles anidados y luego describes un ejercicio entero. Cual es el problema que tienes? Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta y añadir el problema exacto que tienes

Comment: SI porque creo que cuanto mas información haya sobre el problema más pueden ayudarme. Puede que no me haya expresado correctamente.

Comment: Si tu problema es que no sabes hacer el ejercicio... te recomiendo que primero intentes hacer el ejercicio. Si haces una pregunta del tipo "No se hacer esto" y no nos demuestras que te has esforzado, sinceramente, no vamos a hacerlo por tí... el que está aprendiendo a programar (y ergo el que tiene que esforzarse por hacer los deberes), eres tú, no nosotros. Si algo concreto no te sale, podemos ayudarte, pero *todo*? No sería justo ni para los que si están haciéndolo ellos mismos, ni para nosotros

Comment: Hace unos días hice un [ejemplo funcional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/496098/80870) de este juego que puede servir como referencia para que resuelvas el ejercicio. No contempla la parte de si el usuario entra la palabra completa, pero es solo un `if entrada_usuario == palabra:`

Comment: He creado dos listas, una tiene la palabra "hola" [h, o, l, a] y la otra lista tiene la palabra pero en asteriscos [****] si introduces la letra "a" mira si esta en la primera lista, si esta coge la posición y mete la letra en la lista de asteriscos [***a]. Pero no me recorre bien el bucle y muestra lo de la foto que esta mal

Comment: Escúchame una cosa, no se si estas viendo el chorro de código que he puesto que lo he hecho yo mismo.  Me he quedado bloqueado en una parte. Tengo el ejercicio completo pero esa parte me falla. Eso lo primero. Lo segundo si no entiendes algo, preguntas no intentas menospreciar el esfuerzo de otras personas. Y lo tercero con las mismas que has entrado a responder, cierras el navegador y apagas el ordenador y te acuestas por no decirte cuatro cositas

Comment: @aeportugal muchísimas gracias, eso me sirve para ver como puedo arreglar el bucle. Voy a echarle un vistazo, gracias

Comment: No entiendo por qué tienes un bucle anidado. Yo creo que si se cumple `if self.lista_letras[x] == letra_adivinar:` basta hacer `self.lista_letras_asterisco[x] = letra_adivinar`, sin necesidad de otro bucle interno. De hecho es ese otro bucle el que te está metiendo la misma letra en todas las posiciones.